# Jquery Modal window - Modal property breaks code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, modal-dialog

I hope someone can help. I am missing some logic and styles while I am running the form in JQuery modal window with the 'modal' property is set to 'true'. I am trying to utilize the form from http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form.

The same code used outside modal window is running correctly. I am not sure how to fix it and decided to share it with you.

I created a page in JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/vladc77/GcQRg/16 to show the code. However, the modal window cannot be ran from there. As a result, I uploaded the same test in here - http://www.vladcdesign.com/modalWindow

When I set (modal: true) then I am getting the following problems.

1.The check boxes in work hours form should enable/disable menus to set the time

2.“More” check box should show/hide a text field

3.I lost ability to set margins between elements in Hours settings form. Now all menus are touching each other even though I use margins styles. They just don’t apply.

All of these issues are present only while I run this DIV in a modal window. It works OK outside the modal window. I am wondering if someone can help and explain what is wrong with the code. Any advice is highly appreciated.

Comment: Any help? I still cannot solve this issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at both the fiddle and the example you posted on your site, you're getting the following error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: closedHours is not defined

The problem appears to be coming from this line:

```
$(this).append(' <span class="closed custom-checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="closed" value="closed" class="closed" id="closedHoursElement" onchange="closedHours()"><span class="box"><span class="tick"></span></span></span>Closed');
```

Also, the reason you can't get the dialog to load on your fiddle is that you're including the JS files in the wrong order.  It should be jquery, jquery ui, and then jquery ui.selectmenu.

Your change function on the checkboxes also has a bug, it should be something like this:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').change(function() {
    if (!this.checked) {
        $(this).parent().siblings('select').removeAttr("disabled");
    }
    else {
        $(this).parent().siblings('select').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
});
```

Even when I changed all that, the checkboxes still weren't working, so I removed your custom jquery and jquery ui references.  When I did that, they worked fine so something that you've done to customize those is what's causing your problem.  You can view my changes [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bhayden1/GcQRg/17/).

Comment: Thank you for helping me. It seems like I have a hope. I tried to apply your changes into my project but it does not work. I am wondering if you can look it from here: https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=C29483CF3A6A14D!665&authkey=!AAIloQkIUSPNaFY. I am not sure what I am missing but in my case it is still not working. Thank you again.

Comment: After doing a tiny bit more work, it looks like the span wrapper is why the checkbox isn't working correctly.  I removed that and was able to get the toggle working fine.  Unfortunately it doesn't look like the selectmenu widget is paying attention to the disabled attribute of the underlying select.  Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bhayden1/GcQRg/19/

Comment: Sorry, it took more time. I highly appreciate for your efforts and help.

Comment: I found out if I change the modal property to false then the checkboxes are working. You can look here- http://jsfiddle.net/vladc77/GcQRg/22/. However, I am missing the overlay and still missing the styles for select menus. It looks like some issues using modal property. I created new thread to investigate more about it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12877424/missing-select-menu-styles-while-generate-them-with-jquerry-methods. I am wondering if you'll have any ideas on it. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

The **first** `$(document).ready(function(){});` **and second** `$(function() { });` **are the same**, the code will be executed in order they are in these blocks.

However the `$(window).load(function(){ });` **is a little bit differenet**, it gets executed later. Check this [post](http://4loc.wordpress.com/2009/04/28/documentready-vs-windowload/) to see the difference.

You could experminet a little with defining the click event to your "Open modal window" button, and do all of the binding when that fires:

```
$('#create-user').bind('click',function(e){
  // To avoid navigating by link
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  // Do every binding / appending 
  // $('.workDayHours').each(function() { ...
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I will try it. However, I found out that the issue comes from the 'modal' property and had to edit my post. I am wondering if you familiar with http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form. and know the work around this issue. Thank you again.

Comment: I tried your approach but it does not change anything. Thank you anyway.